What healthy habits are necessary to reduce adverse effects of multiple births in a medieval society?
The culture in question is stuck in a pre-industrial era, with few Universities of note and centralized government being rare. It's the relatively decentralized Church equivalent that has to somehow coordinate a health policy to reduce death from childbirth, infant mortality, and all other bad things that happen in a culture where birth control and other such things are not available or even understood.
However, while they have little ability to produce medicines on an industrial scale, they do have some understanding of things like sanitation and germ theory. They also understand through experimentation that healthy mothers are less likely to die than unhealthy ones.
So what types of healthy habits can said decentralized Church advocate in the absence of a proper medical industry and scientific institutes?

Brainstorming is a tough sell on this site because Stack Exchange is designed using a one-specific-question/one-best-answer model. Therefore, asking for an infinite list of things (i.e., an opinion-based open-ended list) is off-topic. On the other hand, asking for a more restrictive finite list of things is on-topic. I'm tempted to embrace the later because the number of sanitary habits in the medieval era is limited... but you've not done your required research. (*Cont*)

... so -1 for not looking at how people lived during the medieval era and answering most if not all of this yourself. But I am bothered that you've not specified a year and location to use as a reference. The medieval era was about 450 ce to 1450 ce. That thousand years saw a LOT of change. And there's a difference between (e.g.) England and Turkey. That could get you a VTC:Needs More Details. So, for my part, a down vote and a VTC pass... but keep in mind for the future, idea generation isn't a good fit for Stack Exchange.

Alcohol is easy to make and it is a great antiseptic. Washing your hands with soap and hot water does wonders. Other than that, they cannot do all that much against child mortality without vaccines. But I am sure that you already knew all this. The point being that it is not clear what answers are being sought beyond the obvious.

I think you might need to take off your Spectacles of Modernity! You're making assumptions based, literally, on 21st century first world American leftist political ideology rather than on an understanding of pre-21st century history, medicine, science, culture, religion, etc.

"They also understand through experimentation that healthy mothers are less likely to die than unhealthy ones."  Do you really mean "through experimentation" or "by observation"?  The former implies a scientific enquiry unconstrained by ethics (making this church really evil) where the latter requires good record-keeping and analysis focused on physical and not spirital factors (which is not very church-like).

@KerrAvon2055 - That's actually pretty church-like, at least in a Medieval setting.

The problem with a decentralized church is that no matter what one person comes up with that would help, the rest of the churches won't follow. For example, look at how the Baptists in the US are very uncoordinated as to common teachings, practices, and acceptance of others. They disagree on women, gays, and many other things. A decentralized church can't coordinate health policy.

@KerrAvon2055 I know what I wrote. And yes, they are very evil. The only reason I won't elaborate on how evil is because of moderation, but they are worse than the Soviets.


birth control and other such things are not available or even understood.

That would be a cave people society, not a medieval one. Medieval Europe knew quite well about birth control. Women had many children not because they were ignorant, but because during those times they generally would suffer all kinds of violence if they refused to have multiple children.
From Wikipedia:

In medieval western Europe, any efforts to halt or prevent pregnancy were deemed immoral by the Catholic Church. Women of the time still used a number of birth control measures such as coitus interruptus, inserting lily root and rue into the vagina, and infanticide after birth.


Now, about:

They also understand through experimentation that healthy mothers are less likely to die than unhealthy ones.

People had the same understanding during medieval times and today, but during medieval times no one cared and if I talk about today half the world will read it as political.

So what types of healthy habits can said decentralized Church advocate in the absence of a proper medical industry and scientific institutes?

Do you want a nice answer (as in being nice, not the answer itself being good), or do you want a realistic one?
Nice: if they have a germ theory, then through trial and error they will have figured out some hygiene habits such as having a proper clean place to give birth, and washing hands. Believe it or not, washing hands before surgeries and such was a revolution in our own world... During the 1800's, which was centuries after medieval time. People, even professionals protested against washing hands back then.
Letting midwives do their midwiving also goes a long way into ensuring safety for the mother and baby.
Realistic answer: Fast, pray, and if you still feel sick let's try some leeches. If you start listening to reason too much it won't be a medieval setting, but more likely a renaissance one.

I briefly thought about the origins of the phrase "cleanliness is next to godliness" because I once heard that it was used to convince people to clean themselves and their environment to avoid the plague... but while the idea was started in 1605 by Francis Bacon it wasn't coined as a phrase until 1791 by Wesley. But even if we accept it, what would it mean? wash your hands, sweep your floor, air out your linen and buy a cat.

Sorry, but people in general in premodern times had lots of kids because so many of them died.  -1 for the errors and modern ideological preconceptions. A woman of that era, regardless of her station in life, her personal desires, or any social norms, literally had to bear nearly ten children just to maintain a stable population.

@elemtilas I don't see how the two are mutually incompatible. Religious requirements and practical, societal needs are usually deeply intertwined.
